# What is the cheapest way to copy elements of one numpy array into the empty spaces in another?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix X that is MxN. I have another matrix Y of the same size.

For every pair of rows X_i and Y_i, I would like to take the k_i nonzero elements of Y_i, and copy them into the first m_i empty spaces in X_i (i.e. those where X_i==0). I know in advance that m_i >= k_i.

What is the cheapest way to do this using Numpy, without using a for loop? These will be large grids (5000x20000) and I will need to do this many times, so I'm going for efficiency here.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: to include an example (making all the nonzero elements in X and Y the same for simplicity):

```
X = [[1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]] 

Y = [[0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 2], [2, 0, 2, 2, 0]]
```

I would like to copy the elements of Y into X such that my output is:

```
Z = [[1, 2, 1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 2, 1, 1], [1, 2, 2, 2, 0]]
```

Here the 2s have been placed in the first available 0 spaces in X.

Comment: You should give a small example, like `M=5, N=3` with `X,Y` and expected output.

Comment: Thanks, I have done- hope that clarifies!

Comment: Show us the loop

Comment: Does the order of the elements in rows of Y need to be preserved in the rows of Z? Anything you can say about the nonzero values (e.g. positive integers as shown, all the same within rows as shown, etc...)?

Answer (score 2):

Note that you asked for a numpy solution. Though vectorized, this solution is not as fast as the numba solution provided. This function is not shortcircuited thus considerably slower than the numba solution. Please consider the numba solution.

```
import numpy as np

def fill_empty_np(X, Y):
  i1 = X == 0
  i2 = Y != 0
  X[(i1.cumsum(1) <= i2.sum(1, keepdims = True)) & i1] = Y[i2]
```

---

```
X = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
Y = np.array([[0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 2], [2, 0, 2, 2, 0]])
fill_empty_np(X, Y)
print(X)
```

Comment: This is the same idea as my solution, only better.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) + parallelize the task. I've managed to fill the 5000x20_000 array in ~84msec on my AMD 5700x:

```py
from statistics import median
from timeit import repeat

import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange


@njit(parallel=True)
def fill_empty(X, Y):
    for i in prange(len(X)):
        row = X[i]
        idx_Y = 0
        for j, v in enumerate(row):
            if v == 0:
                while idx_Y < len(row):
                    if Y[i, idx_Y] != 0:
                        X[i, j] = Y[i, idx_Y]
                        idx_Y += 1
                        break
                    idx_Y += 1


X = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
Y = np.array([[0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 2], [2, 0, 2, 2, 0]])

fill_empty(X, Y)
print(X)


def setup_X_Y():
    X = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(5000, 20_000))
    Y = np.random.choice([0, 2], size=(5000, 20_000))
    return X, Y


repeats = repeat(
    "fill_empty(X, Y)",
    setup="X, Y = setup_X_Y()",
    number=1,
    repeat=10,
    globals=globals(),
)
print(f"median of {len(repeats)} repeats = {median(repeats)}")
```

Prints:

```
[[1 2 1 1 0]
 [1 2 2 1 1]
 [1 2 2 2 0]]

median of 10 repeats = 0.08158597500005271
```

Comment: Great solution. `np.random.choice` should take `size=(5000,20000)`? Also this takes me ~0.6s on a 5800x. Maybe that depends on the zeros in `X` and `Y`, which is not totally controlled by this random operation.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks :) 5800x is practically the same as 5700x so you should get the same result as me. When I turn off the paralelization (`parallel=False`) I get ~0.6 seconds too. So maybe some system-library isn't present? There is [diagnostics](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html#numba-parallel-diagnostics) built-in in numba. (I've also reworked the test and used `statistics.median()`)